# Как передать Set готовый Set?

Tags: java

Вот у `List` допустим есть такой метод

```
List <String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("", "", ""));
```

В этом случае `Arrays.asList("", "", "")` передает сразу список...

Вот вопрос в том, есть ли у `Set`, что то аналогичное?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet%28java.util.Collection%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пожалуйста:

```
final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("","",""));
```

Comment: Блин я пробовал у меня показывало ошибку)) Спасибо, теперь все ок